# remove `format: uuid` from drf-spectacular generated openapi schema

Tags: openapi, uuid, apigee, drf-spectacular

Google Apigee does not currently support `format: uuid` types. Is there any way to suppress `format: uuid` from `AlbumSerializer` when generating the openapi schema using drf-spectacular?

```
@extend_schema(
    request=AlbumCreationSerializer,
    responses={201: AlbumSerializer},
)
def create(self, request):
    # your non-standard behaviour
    return super().create(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

My kludge solution is to monkey patch `OpenApiTypes.UUID` to cast UUID type as string:

```
from drf_spectacular.types import OPENAPI_TYPE_MAPPING

OPENAPI_TYPE_MAPPING.update({OpenApiTypes.UUID: {'type': 'string'}})
```